# jsoup returning <thead> tags when <tr> tags are selected?

Tags: html, jsoup

I am new to jsoup and might be using it wrong. I was going to contact the mailing list but jsoup [instructs to post here first](http://jsoup.org/discussion). I am trying to select `<td>` elements from a table but the first element returned is actually `<thead>`. Is this the wrong way to get the `<td>` elements for a given table? If so, what is the right way?

Simple representative issue below:

HTML:

```html
<table id="results_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Header1</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Test:

```
String pageHtml = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.html"));
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageHtml);
Element table = doc.getElementById("results_table");
Elements trs = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

System.out.println("Size: " + trs.size());
System.out.println("First Element: " + trs.get(0).html());
System.out.println("Second Element: " + trs.get(1).html());
```

Received Output:

```
Size: 2
First Element: <th>Header1</th>
Second Element: <td>td1</td>
```

Expected Output:

```
Size: 1
First Element: <td>td1</td>
//Index out of bounds exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, jsoup is putting the `<th>` element in its own `<tr>` when parsing the HTML document, resulting in the following DOM:

```html
<table id="results_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since a table cell must reside in a table row (which means your source HTML file is invalid), I would expect any HTML processor, particularly a Web browser, to do the same (this would not happen in XML mode, though, which jsoup does not support).

Instead, you can use `doc.select()` with a CSS selector to get just the rows that are in `<tbody>`:

```
String pageHtml = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.html"));
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageHtml);
Elements trs = doc.select("#results_table tbody tr");

System.out.println("Size: " + trs.size());
System.out.println("First Element: " + trs.get(0).html());
System.out.println("Second Element: " + trs.get(1).html()); // IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

(You can also use a series of `getElementsByTag()` calls but this would require extra traversals and iteration; using `doc.select()` is much cleaner.)

If you don't need to go through the rows first and simply want to get the `<td>` elements directly, you can do so:

```
String pageHtml = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.html"));
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageHtml);
Element table = doc.getElementById("results_table");
Elements tds = table.getElementsByTag("td");
```

Comment: Feeling pretty foolish at this point. I did not realize the page I'm crawling was invalid html. Apologies for the "dumb" question and appreciate the valuable in-depth answer. I will have to learn more about the CSS selector methodology as it certainly gets me more expressiveness (and resolves my issue at hand). Thank you, and again sorry for not realizing it was invalid html.

Comment: @Russ: That's alright, websites aren't exactly known for being standards-compliant so you'll probably find yourself dealing with invalid HTML more often than not :)